# convert the given string s to the target string t

Tags: string, algorithm, pointers

You need to convert the given string **s** to the target string **t**. You can only perform two types of operations: delete one subsequence "tcp" from **s** or add one subsequence "tcp" to **s**.
For example, given s as "tcbdp", after one operation, **s** can become "bd" or "tctbcdpp".

**Please determine if s can be transformed into t after several operations.**

Note: The order of subsequences in the original string is also from left to right, but they may not be contiguous.

**Input Description:**
The first line contains a positive integer q, representing the number of inquiries.
Each subsequent pair of lines represents one inquiry: each line is a string, representing s and t respectively.
1 ≤ q ≤ 10^3
The length of the strings does not exceed 10^3.

**Output Description:**
Output q lines, each line containing the answer to one inquiry. If s can be transformed into t, output "Yes". Otherwise, output "No".

**Example:**

Input

```
3
tcbdp
bd
tcbdp
tctbcdpp
tcp
abc
```

Output

```
Yes
Yes
No
```

p.s.I know this problem can be solved using dynamic programming, but I want to know how to write the algorithm using **two pointers**.

Comment: I don't understand how dynamic programming could be used here. What is the recurrence relation (in words would be fine).

Answer (score 2):

Being able to add `tcp` subsequences is more powerful than it looks.  For example, you can move any `t`, `c`, or `p` to the end:

- `XtY` -> `XtYtcp` -> `XYt`
- `XcY` -> `tXcYcp` -> `XYc`
- `XpY` -> `tcXpYp` -> `XYp`

And, of course, if you move all the `t`s, then all the `c`s, then all the `p`s, then you can remove all `tcp` triplets until only 2 of those letters remain.

Two strings are inter-transformable if performing this operation on both of them produces the same "canonicalized" result.

Equivalently, two strings are inter-transformable if their counts of `t`s, `c`s, and `p`s differ by the same amount, and if their subsequences of *other* characters are the same.

A "two pointer algorithm" would be to walk through both strings, skipping and counting `t`s, `c`s, and `p`s, while comparing the other characters.

Comment: "if you move all the `t`s, then all the `c`s, then all the `p`s" My interpretation of the puzzle is that "tcp" is a sequence, not just a collection. In other words, it needs to be in order. Consider the string "cpt".

Comment: @Ouroborus cpt -> TcptCP / TCPtcp-> tcp

Comment: I'm not sure how you get that result from your description "if you move all the `t`s, then all the `c`s, then all the `p`s, then you can remove all `tcp` triplets". The steps would seem to be: Start with "cpt"; Move all `t`s to the end, resulting in "cpt"; Move all `c`s to the end, resulting in "ptc"; Move all `p`s to the end, resulting in "tcp"; Remove all `tcp` triplets, resulting in an empty string.

Comment: Alright. But the puzzle description seems to indicate that the order does matter. In other words, "tcp" found in that order could be removed but "cpt" (or any other order) could not be removed. So when given "cpt" and "" the response should be "No", but based on your solution, the response would be "Yes".

Comment: I've just shown you that "cpt" can, in fact, be removed, and that the answer should be "Yes".  cpt -> TcptCP / TCPtcp-> tcp -> ''

Comment: Is it that, if you add enough "tcp", you can get to a state where you can remove all "tcp" regardless of what the original ordering may have been?

Comment: Yes, I proved it.